# Unable to Determine Request Header Limiter

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I'm new to using apache and working on a company product I've been hit with a 405 error with a PUT request. Looking at methods of limiting request headers - it appears this can only be done using Limit(s) inside either the httpd.conf file, httpdchild.conf files, or inside .hcaccess file embedded in the directory in which the rules apply. No limits apply in any of these scenarios and `AllowOverrides None` is set from root, preventing any hcaccess files from modifying the request header allow list.

Are there some other methods to inhibiting request methods (mostly PUT) from the allow list which I'm unaware of? I've seen the way in which TRACE is toggled on and off is using TraceEnable, but I have been unable to find a similar directive for PUT. Any help and added information would be appreciated.

```
$ curl -i -X OPTIONS --user username:password localhost
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Tue, 09 Feb 2021 15:41:20 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/7.4.3 WCM/1.0.27031
    Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS,TRACE
    Content-Length: 0
    Content-Type: httpd/unix-directory
```

Comment: Do you actually have a web app configured and running that would handle the PUT requests? It looks like you do not.

Comment: The web server is used to handle certain incoming requests from software rather than a web app.

Comment: Then how do you expect to handle PUT requests?